# Automatically connect Bluetooth device to Mac

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, peripheral

I have a MacBook Pro (running Mavericks) and a Bluetooth Speaker (JBL Flip). I want the two to connect automatically whenever they are nearby and powered on. Is that possible?

Currently I have to click the Bluetooth icon in the menubar of the Mac, select the device, and click connect each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it has been a while ago I did that, but the ON comes from your speakers, not from Mac.

Mac see is as it sees many other BT around.

By pressing the power button on your speaker (I think for 3 seconds or longer) should tell your Mac to engage that device.

Comment: 1) I have read that elsewhere, but it's not working for me
2) Assuming this does work, how does the speaker know to connect to my Mac (and not my iPhone, say, with which it was paired at some point as well). Or does it simply connect to the last paired device?

Comment: Ops..that might be you problem, try disabling from one of the devices or move it out of the range (next room)

Comment: Did that as well. Still no luck. :/

Comment: Suddenly this seems to work now :) Basically, I have to turn the device on and keep its power button pressed till it pairs with my mac.

Comment: There you go, I did not remember how long you have to push it, and it is model dependent, but we have another happy visitor :)